# Firebase auth.currentUser error using typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, firebase, firebase-authentication

When configuring typescript with firebase, I am getting the following error: `Argument of type 'User | null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'User'. Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'User'.`

**The error is here: auth.currentUser** It is unclear to me what type it would be.

```
updateProfile(auth.currentUser, {
                    displayName: name
                }
```

Full code:

```
import { getAuth, createUserWithEmailAndPassword, signOut, onAuthStateChanged, signInWithEmailAndPassword, updateProfile } from "firebase/auth";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import FirebaseInitialization from "../Firebase/Firebase.init";



FirebaseInitialization()

interface IUseFirebaseProps {
}

const UseFirebase: React.FunctionComponent<IUseFirebaseProps> = (props) => {
    const [user, setUser] = useState({})
    const [error, setError] = useState('')
    const [admin, setAdmin] = useState(false)
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true)
    const auth = getAuth()


      // REGISTER WITH EMAIL AND PASSWORD
      const RegisterUser = (email: string, password:string, name:string, history: any) => {
        setIsLoading(true)
        createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
            .then((userCredential) => {
                const newUser = { email, displayName: name };
                setUser(newUser);
                setError('')
                updateProfile(auth.currentUser, {
                    displayName: name
                }).then(() => {
                }).catch((error) => {
                });
                history.replace('/');
            })
            .catch((error) => {

                const errorMessage = error.message;
                setError(errorMessage)
            }).finally(() => setIsLoading(false));
    }
  return <h2>Firebase</h2>
};

export default UseFirebase;
```

How can I solve this? can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value of `auth.currentUser` can be `null`. In this case you can pass [`User`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/auth.user) object directly from [`UserCredential`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/auth.usercredential) object. Try refactoring the code as shown below:

```
const RegisterUser = async (email: string, password: string, name: string, history: any) => {
  setIsLoading(true)
  const userCredential = await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
  
  const newUser = {
    email,
    displayName: name
  };
  
  setUser(newUser);
  setError('')
  
  // Pass userCredential.user instead of auth.currentUser
  updateProfile(userCredential.user, {
    displayName: name
  }).then(() => {}).catch((error) => {});
    history.replace('/');
  })
}
```

Comment: thank you. Can you please help me How can I return the function RegisterUser? I want the custom hook which I created I want to return the function like this `return [RegisterUser]` but get an error that `Type '((email: string, password: string, name: string, history: any) => Promise<void>)[]' is missing the following properties from type 'ReactElement<any, any>': type, props, key`

Comment: @FatheKarim I can't see any return statement in the provided code. It might be best to post another question with details of new issue .